# How to Convert PDF file to DOC file in Android App Programmatic

Tags: java, android

I m developing android that convert `pdf` file to word file without using internet can some one please help me on this. I have one solution but throw file format exception :

I have search many open source library but its cant help me

```
 Document pdfDocument = new Document(new File(selectedImagePath).getAbsolutePath());

   String path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()) + "/Test.doc";
                pdfDocument.save(path, SaveFormat.Doc);
```

error :

```
class com.aspose.pdf.internal.ms.System.ArgumentException: Save a document to a doc format is not supported.
```

Comment: This question breaks multiple rules of the site - first it is not clear what exactly are you asking as it doesn't go far from asking the help and describing what you have done. Second it seems that you want recommendation for a library which is prohibited too. Finally the question sounds too broad though it is in line with the first remark that you are not clear exactly what do you ask as only clear question you have made is "I need help", other lines are description of your work.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
static String pdftoText(String fileName) {
    PDFParser parser;
    String parsedText = null;
    PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = null;
    PDDocument pdDoc = null;
    COSDocument cosDoc = null;
    File file = new File(fileName);
    if (!file.isFile()) {
        System.err.println("File " + fileName + " does not exist.");
        return null;
    }
    try {
        parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(file));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Unable to open PDF Parser. " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    try {
        parser.parse();
        cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
        pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
        parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err
                .println("An exception occured in parsing the PDF Document."
                        + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (cosDoc != null)
                cosDoc.close();
            if (pdDoc != null)
                pdDoc.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return parsedText;
}
```

From https://pdfbox.apache.org

Comment: i need convert whole pdf file to word file as you mention your code its only convert text string